# Show that $f.g$ is also integrable over $X$ with respect to $\mu.$

Tags: integration, proof-writing, solution-verification

In the following problem, $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a measure space, measurable means with respect to  $\mathcal{M},$ and integrable means with respect to $\mu.$

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative measurable functions on $X$ for which $f^2$ and $g^2$ are integrable over $X$ with respect to $\mu.$ Show that $f.g$ is also integrable over $X$ with respect to $\mu.$

**My trial:**

First, observe that $$ f.g = \frac{1}{2}[(f + g)^2 - f^2 - g^2]. $$ then the proof follows directly, but I am confused about how to show that $(f + g)^2$ is integrable as the given did say that $f$ and $g$ are integrable. could anyone help me in this step please?

Comment: Hölder's inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it would be easier to use
$$ \vert f\cdot g \vert \leq f^2+g^2.$$
Thus, we can dominate our function by an integrable one and therefore it is integrable.

Comment: Is this true by the AM-GM inequality?or by what?

Comment: This is just (for $a,b\geq 0$) $$ab \leq  2ab \leq a^2 + b^2.$$

Comment: Is it true for functions also?

Comment: Sure, because inequality $\varphi\leq \phi$ just means: For every $x$ in the common domain of definition we have $\varphi(x)\leq \phi(x)$.